# Extension creation fails with no information

Tags: javascript, safari, safari-extension, browser-extension

I have a browser extension that works in Firefox, IE and Chrome and I'm currently porting it to safari.

I followed the instructions on the apple developer site and also renamed the extension folder to `myext.safariextension` . I got a certificate and I think the safari extension builder recognizes it.

However, for some reason creating the extension fails. I get the following message:

[image: fails and don't know why]

I have no idea how to tackle the issue. A google search, an SO search and asking in the SO chat room yielded no results.

Any help would be appreciated, even if it's just directing me towards the right solution. This is Safari 5 on windows if that helps.

Comment: Note, I close-voted this as this is an issue with Windows Safari 5.1. Windows Safari is discontinued at the moment, if you're building an extension, just use a mac, this problem does not persist there.

Comment: Good Guy Benjamin Close votes his own question ^_^